# Layers Panel Disappeared Completely

Tags: qgis, osx, gui

I see that other people have mentioned losing track of the layers panel, and people have rightly pointed out that it can be restored by View > Panels > Layers.

But in my install on MacOS 10.14.3, the layers panel has disappeared entirely from the list.

[image: I get two copies of the Browser panel, but none of the Layers panel]

Same thing when I right click on the gray area above the browser. Layers panel doesn't exist.

Unless I'm missing something here – QGIS is *** functionally unusable without the layers panel ***. I tried

restarting qgis
trashing the preferences
restarting the machine
reinstalling an earlier version (3.4)
but no luck!

Comment: Could it be removed in [`settings / interface customization`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#customization) ?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly it! Thank you so much! I went into that screen to try to make the icon options more like version 2 – where the default buttons were "add layer," which I use all the time, but in v3 they are "create layer." I must have deselected the layers panel there. There was a delay – effect must have been postponed until I restarted, so I didn't realize what a self-own I'd committed. Thanks!

Comment: Great! I will change the comment to an answer then

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the interface via the menu [`settings / interface customization`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#customization). If you deselect a panel there, it will completely be removed: the panel itself and any reference from right click / menus.